# Remove code duplication with an ostream variable

Tags: c++, ofstream, ostream

I have

```cpp
void fnc(std::ofstream& file){
    std::cout << x;
    file << x;
}
```

with `x` something complicated and I would like to remove the code duplication.

I tried something like

```cpp
void fnc(std::ofstream& file){
    std::ostream os;
    os << x;
    std::cout << os;
    file << os;
}
```

but it doesn't work. What's the best way to remove code duplication with the operator << ?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I think you wanted std::ostringstream instead of std::ostream: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233710/how-do-i-use-the-ostringstream-properly-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233710/how-do-i-use-the-ostringstream-properly-in-c)

Comment: Or you can call fnc(std::cout)  and get the cout out of the first code.

Comment: I want the thing both outputed and printed in an external file, but I didn't want to copy paste for future modification (ouput and file must be the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to drescherjm the solution is the following :

```cpp
void fnc(std::ofstream& file){
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << x;
    std::cout << os.str();
    file << os.str();
}
```